# Marble & Urn in language R

Tags: r, probability

Hey guys I'm new to language R and here's a HW question from our professor which is basically asking u to randomly assign 1123 marbles to 97 urns.. and you need to make a script to    simulate this process, and you'll need to get a vector with 97 randomly assigned numbers with a sum of 1123

so here's what I've got so far. I'm pretty sure the part with randomly assignment is alright, it's just that I don't know how I should use a counter to sum up all the marbles in the same urn.   Could anyone help please? thank u thank u thank u!!

```
for(i in 1:1123){
    x=floor(runif(1,1,98))  
    for (j in 1:97){
      Count=0
      if (j=x){
      Count=Count+1
      }
    }  
print(Count)
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a shift key and avoid greetings and thanks. It's the SO Way.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to choose, 1123 times, where to put a marble among 97 urns.
You can use `sample` (see `?sample`):

```
s <- sample(1:97, 1123, replace=TRUE)
```

You can tabulate results with `table(s)` (that is a little confusing when printed), or convert it to a `data.frame`  to "check":

```
df <- data.frame(table(s))
nrow(df)     # 97 urns
sum(df$Freq) # 1123 marbles
```